# Use raspberry pi as remote speaker

Tags: audio, wifi, shairplay

I was able to install shairport on my raspberry pi (whezzy, Xorg disabled) wich is connected to my speakers and my router. This way I was able to send Audio from my notebook (Airfoil for windows) and from my Android Nexus 4 (with AirAudio) to the speakers via WiFi. But AirPlay has a high latency of about 2 seconds wich makes watching movies impossible. Is there another way to stream the whole audio output of a windows and an android device via WiFi to the raspberry pi but without that latency? I think the speed of a WiFi connection should normally be fast enough. Thanks :)

Comment: Check out http://jackaudio.org/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, try TuneBlade for audio streaming. It can synchronize Airplay audio with VLC media player's video.